# How to add Javascript extraction function in Druid?

Tags: javascript, extract, druid

I am not able to add this fucntion to Druid. (Don't know how to add one)

I trying to preprocess data coming from druid.

```
function transformData(data) {
    const res = {};
    const dataArray = data.split(',');

    dataArray.map(value => {
        res[value] = true;
    });

    if ('abc' in res) {
        return 'abc';
    } else {
        return 'xyz;
    }

    return '';
}
```

I want to access this transformation function as a part of SQL query while querying from Druid.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Information on how to use Javascript with Apache Druid is given on the documentation page below.

- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/javascript/

Note that Javascript is not a recommended solution for production. You should therefore see if you can craft the same function using [SQL](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql) or [native](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/math-expr) expressions. Failing that, take a look at the documentation on how to add your own [extension module](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/modules).

It looks like you're trying to do something with arrays? If so, check out the new ARRAY type in Druid and its associated functions. A Python notebook on this is available in the learn-druid repo under the "ingestion" section.

- https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid

For further help, join the #dev channel in the project's [Slack channel](https://druid.apache.org/community).

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation, Peter!
I want to clean my code where I have used SQL expressions provided by Druid as you mentioned.

For my case I want to check whether some entries are present in an array or not and based on that I will decide to return a value in the respective select statement. The Javascript function given in the description will suffice my requirements if I can call that function while querying from Druid.

Ex, select transform(inputArray) as output from ...

Let me know if this is possible if not what's your take on a problem like this?